# Not able to set the url for site on IIS localhost

Tags: iis

I want to access the site hosted on localhost using the domain name i.e. www.practical.com (on IIS 8)

With the following settings I am able to access the site with url http://localhost:81/ but not using www.practical.com.

My settings are given below;
Site hosted in Sites Root Folder and just Default Website as following ;

Sites 
  -Default Web Site
  -WebApp

Bindings are as following;

-IP Address :  All Unassigned
-Port : 81
-Host Name : "" --> www.practical.com did not work so i have kept it empty

Hosts File Settings are as following;

localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 practical.com --> This does not make an effect
please let me know what extra settings I need to do.
Thanks in advance,
Anil

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem, by adding an entry into hosts.ics
    127.0.0.1 www.practical.com
This was the file I had to modify as my window 8.1 was looking for the entry in this file.

Answer (score 0):

The host `www.practical.com` is different from `practical.com`. You need an entry in your hosts file of:

```
127.0.0.1 www.practical.com
```

You can test the difference between the entries yourself by doing the following at a command line:

```
nslookup practical.com
nslookup www.practical.com
```

With your current hosts file, this will return 127.0.0.1 for the first and unknown (or 208.91.197.39 as is being returned for me!) for the second. Once you've added a hosts entry for `www.practical.com`, both should return `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Added entry   127.0.0.1 www.practical.com but still does not work. Location of hosts file is in C:// windows/system32/drivers/etc. nslookup www.practical.com returns 208.91.197.39 and nslookup practical.com returns 103.8.44.5 for me after adding this entry to the hosts. Is the location of the hosts correct?

Comment: Any changes in the web.config required ?